# sonarqube includes bogus module containing its own log files

Tags: java, configuration, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have just started using Sonarqube and have one project analyzed so far.
When using the "Issues" search facility the UI hangs.

It turns out to be caused by the fact that I have somehow included files called AVJ9.... which turns out to be sonarqube's own log files being included in my database.

They are not part of my single project but still causes the "Issues" search to hang unless I exclude them from the search.

I cannot find a way to remove or even ignore them (Neither excluding the path, the filename, ... makes any difference).
And I don't understand how they got there in the first place. I an not including their location in my analysis.

Any clues?

Comment: Could you show your project structure including the locations of the extraneous files? Also, it may be useful to know scanner type (SonarQube Scanner?, for Maven? for Ant? ...) and versions of scanner, SQ server and relevant language plugins.

Comment: The extraneous files are named after files which I using "find" can locate in /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.3/data/ce/logs/REPORT.

Comment: The extraneous files are named after files which I using "find" can locate in /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.3/data/ce/logs/REPORT.
But in the UI they are claimed to be in various folder in what is actually my project. Like "./com/hp/ov/activ...". Which they are not.
I am using "/opt/sonarqube/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin/sonar-runner" for my scanner. I call it directly via a shell command from Jenkins.
The Database is Oracle XE (11.2)

To me it looks like some kind of data corruption but how can I clean it up without deleting the data entered already by the users?

Comment: I realised today that the "Background Tasks" view does actually (since I upgraded to use Oracle) include a "Logs" link for each task run. And that the data shown is the content of my bogus code modules. So it seems that it is correct that the log files are in my DB. But why do they show up as source modules to be analysed making the "Issues->Search" hang unless they are excluded?